# f(x, y) is a function find dy/dx

Tags: calculus

I saw that in such a case

dy/dx =-(∂f/∂x)/(∂f/∂y) ... Eq 1

I searched a lot about partial Derivatives but the only thing I saw that was in partial derivatives we treat all other variables constant other than the one with which respect to which we are differentiating

I am familiar with normal derivatives
Whenever I would get something like
y=G(u), x=H(u)

I used to fine dy/du and dx/du and then I used to divide both

And when I saw Eq 1

I thought the same
Thing to multiply and divide by ∂f and we would be done but we get a negative sign as in Eq 1

I want to ask why did this problem came up if ∂f, df don't have a lot of difference in the way we work with them

Another thing I saw that to find dy/dx
In f(x, y) we equate f(x, y) =0 and then we differentiate both side with respect to x and find dy/dx but I didn't understand the logic behind it

(I don't have any mentor from whome I can ask this please help me my school teacher said this won't come in test so you don't need all these)

If it seems like that I have incomplete knowledge about some topic please mention that with a source from where I can study about it

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: As written, this isn't true. If $f(x,y)=0$ is some equation, then we can get $dy/dx,$ but absent such an equation, $f(x,y)$ alone does not give us any relationship between $x,y.$

Comment: It's hard to answer without more context on the example you saw, but it might be related to [implicit differentiation](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Applied_Calculus_(Calaway_Hoffman_and_Lippman)/02%3A_The_Derivative/2.12%3A_Implicit_Differentiation_and_Related_Rates).

Comment: @Karl sir in short just to summarize my question without going in detail the main point is that in ∂y/∂x Or in dy/dx Or in anything like that can't we just treat dy, dx or ∂y, ∂x as single entities just as same as saying to treat anyone of them from dy, dx Or something as single variable so that one can cancel them divide or  take reciprocal or something

Comment: @Lemmon  sir i think you misread Eq 1

Comment: @AnshuGupta well the answer to that question is no. That derivative notation is meant to *resemble* division, but it's not actually a fraction and the individual symbols are not quantities on their own.

Comment: @Karl for example in y=f(x)  don't we define dy, dx both as an infinitesimal quantity such that dy=f(x+x') -f(x), dx=x' where x'→0 , also while solving some differential equations  don't we just multiply by dx or something both side so as to make the form of an integral?